# For $m,n \in \Bbb N$, $E^m \times E^n$ is homeomorphic to $E^{m+n}$.

Tags: general-topology

For $m,n \in \Bbb N$, $E^m \times E^n$ is homeomorphic to $E^{m+n}$, where each cell $E^k = \{x \in \Bbb R^k : |x| \le 1\}$ and $|x|$ is the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^k$.

I figure let $f((\langle x_1, ..., x_m\rangle, \langle y_1, ..., y_n \rangle)) = \langle x_1, ..., x_m, y_1, ..., y_n \rangle $ is a bijection, but I'm having trouble showing it's continuous.  I know that the continuous bijective mapping of a compact $T_2$ space onto another compact $T_2$ space is a homeomorphism, but I can't figure out how to show that this is continuous.

Comment: It's better to use \langle and \rangle in place of < and >.

Comment: What definition of continuous are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the LaTeX code tip.  I'm using $(\forall V \in T_1)(f^{-1}(V) \in T)$  With $T_1$ being the codomain's topology.  If I let $V =$ a product of $m+n$ open balls, $f^{-1}$(open balls) is where I can't figure anything out.

Comment: (Looks better!) Okay, so you need to prove that the inverse image of any open set in the codomain is open in the domain. It's probably going to be easier to prove that the inverse image of any *basis* set for the codomain's topology is open in the domain. Do you know that this is sufficient (or can figure out why)? What is a basis set in $E^{m+n}$, and what is its preimage?

Comment: Open cubes also form a basis for the topology. These are nicer than open balls in this context.

Comment: @GregMartin A basis set is a product of open sets from each $E^k$  So for $V \in T_1, V = O_1 \times O_2 \times ... \times O_{m+n}$  but the inverse image of this is what confuses me.

Comment: Perhaps try simple examples, like $m=n=1$ or $m=2,n=1$. You have all the information you need now; I think you just need to stare at it and realize that all the pieces are in front of you!

Comment: $f^{-1} = \{ (\langle x,y \rangle) \in E^m \times E^n : f( \langle x, y \rangle) \in \prod_{i=1}^{m+n} B_{r_i}(a_i) \}$.  So this turns into $ f^{-1} = \{ (\langle x,y \rangle) \in E^m \times E^n : \langle x_1, ..., x_m, y_1, ..., y_n \rangle \in \prod_{i=1}^{m+n} B_{r_i}(a_i) \}$.  And since each $x, y, r,$ and $i$ are arbitrary, this is open in $E^m \times E^n$ because it's a product of open balls?

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1,2,\dots$ it can be shown that $E^{k}$ and $\left[-1,1\right]^{k}$
are homeomorphic.

For every $z\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$ with $\left|z\right|=1$ there is
a unique $r\left(z\right)>0$ with $r\left(z\right)z\in\partial\left[-1,1\right]^{k}$.

The map $z\mapsto r\left(z\right)z$ projects elements of
$\partial E^{k}$ to elements of $\partial\left[-1,1\right]^{k}$
and is a homeomorphism.

Now let $\rho:E^{k}\to\left[-1,1\right]^{k}$ be prescribed by $x\mapsto r\left(\frac{x}{\left|x\right|}\right)x$
if $x\neq\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{0}\mapsto\mathbf{0}$.

Then $\rho$ is an extension of $r$ and can be shown to be a homeomorphism as well.

As a result of this we have:

$$E^{m+n}\simeq\left[-1,1\right]^{m+n}=\left[-1,1\right]^{m}\times\left[-1,1\right]^{n}\simeq E^{m}\times E^{n}$$